# Can a Macbook Pro A1398 drive two Dell U2515H and at what resolution?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution

I'm planning to use 2x Dell U2515H monitors with my 15" mid-2015 Macbook Pro 2.2Ghz (model number A1398) with Intel Iris Pro Graphics. [According to Apple](http://www.apple.com/za/macbook-pro/specs-retina/), it can drive:

> Dual display and video mirroring: simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to **3840x2160** pixels on up to two external displays, both at millions of colours.

Additionally, the HDMI video output van:

> Support for 4096x2160 resolution at 24Hz

Will I be able to drive two of these bad boys at native resolution of 2560x1440?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.2-15-iris-only-mid-2015-retina-display-specs.html)…

> This model supports a simultaneous maximum resolution up to 3840x2160 on two external displays via Thunderbolt 2. Alternately, it can support a single display up to 3840x2160 via Thunderbolt 2 and a single 1080p display at up to 60 Hz, 3840x2160 at 30 Hz, or 4096x2160 at 24 Hz via HDMI.

According to [Dell](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?s=bsd&c=us&l=en&sku=480-ACRZ&cs=04)..

> For convenient connections to other devices in your workspace, the U2515H provides two HDMI (MHL) ports, a DisplayPort, a mini-DisplayPort and five USB 3.0 ports.

So, theoretically, both over Thunderbolt > Mini DP
or one over Thunderbolt & one over HDMI at 30Hz